# Find out all the python modules available on my machine

Tags: python, pip

I want to see all the modules installed on my machine. I tried "pip list" but it shows only packages.

```
> =>pip list Package    Version
> ---------- ------- 
> pip        20.0.2 
> setuptools 40.6.2 
> WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 20.1.1 is available.
> You should consider upgrading via the
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -m
> pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I want to see all the modules like re, time, sys and so on.

Comment: These are part of the standard lib. You can still list them on demand, e.g. `python -c "import re; print(re.__file__)" | xargs dirname | xargs ls -l`

Answer (score 2):

You can also go to your python shell and type `help('modules')`. This will return a list of local modules on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to find all the python modules installed on your machine. Just open command line and type "pip freeze" a list will appear of all modules.